# Bitlocker not requiring PIN on startup?

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

I have an operating system drive encrypted with Bitlocker, set via group policy to require TPM and PIN at startup. A second drive auto-unlocks with the system drive. Today, I noticed when I booted into a WinPE environment via USB that, while that second drive is properly locked, the system drive was unlocked. Booting from that USB, I was of course not required to enter the PIN.

**Is this intended behavior? If so, how can I make it so the drive only unlocks with the PIN?**

*UPDATE: Answered below [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686). Additional information: an external key was stored on the WinPE USB drive by Macrium Reflect.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't have been the TPM at all, because that key is sealed in such a way that it becomes inaccessible when any part of the boot process changes. (That's the whole idea of TPM-based unlocking: whether with PIN or without, the key is not revealed to anything other than the "real" OS loader.)

My guess is that the disk was unlocked using an *external key*, i.e. a `<uuid>.bek` file stored on the same USB stick. This is possible if you had the WinPE stick connected when Windows asked about storing a recovery key.

Comment: It seems you are correct. I made a Linux Mint USB drive to test, and the system drive was properly locked there. The original WinPE drive mentioned in my question was actually made by Macrium Reflect, and while I did not find a .bek file on it, perhaps it stores it in another way for recovery purposes.

Comment: Confirmed: Macrium Reflect has an option to automatically unlock Bitlocker drives in its Rescue Media building options, which is on by default. Good to know that I had a way to unlock my encrypted drive laying in a cupboard not two meters away from the machine itself...

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this today and spent a good deal of my day being paranoid that somehow my BitLocker enabled volume was not setup correctly, and testing various scenarios. I even set up BitLocker to require an enhanced PIN (password) but the Macrium WinPE USB drive was still able to automatically unlock the volume. I tested the Macrium WinPE USB drive on another BitLocker encrypted laptop and it did not have access to that volume so I Googled "Macrium Reflect BitLocker" and found the answer. It is scary that the default option is "Automatically unlock BitLocker Volumes" yet there is no warning in big red letters to let you know that the WinPE USB drive should be properly secured since it has the BitLocker decryption key on it! The Macrium KB that mentions this is below. Now I know about this and I also learned how to force a PIN + TPM on my BitLocker volume.
https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Adding+BitLocker+support+to+Windows+PE